# Flask with mod_wsgi "error : bad argument type for built-in operation"

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

```
[Fri Sep 25 19:05:17 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 mod_wsgi/4.4.13 Python/2.7.10 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Fri Sep 25 19:29:15 2015] [error]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 252, in vasp2
[Fri Sep 25 19:29:15 2015] [error]     oszi = open(jobpath+jobname+"/OSZICAR","r")
[Fri Sep 25 19:29:15 2015] [error] TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

When i run `python2.7 __init__.py` the error doesn't appear.
But the error occurred when run as 'Apache (httpd)'.

I installed mod_wsgi by compiling with python2.7.
(Similarly these errors occurred.
On my python2.7 command, no import error. But run as 'Apache' the import error occurred.)
My English skill is terrible, please understand me...

Comment: open module is `from io import open`

Comment: What is the value of `jobpath` and `jobname` when it is working vs. when it is run as Apache?